# Why changing the tkinter font on one widget affects this other widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tk_font

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry("800x600")
style = ttk.Style()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Assign the first style
font_name = style.lookup("TLabelframe.Label", "font")
this_is_the_font_object: tk.font.Font = tk_font.nametofont(font_name).copy()
this_is_the_font_object.config(weight="bold")
style.configure("TLabelframe.Label", foreground="#0C529A", font=this_is_the_font_object)
print(this_is_the_font_object)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Assign the second style
font_name = style.lookup("TLabel", "font")
this_is_the_font_object: tk.font.Font = tk_font.nametofont(font_name).copy()
this_is_the_font_object.config(weight="bold")
style.configure("My.Bold.TLabel", font=this_is_the_font_object)
print(this_is_the_font_object)
# Why does this change the first style as well?
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


lf = ttk.LabelFrame(window, text="Frame Label:")
lf.pack()
ttk.Label(lf, text="Just a Label", style="My.Bold.TLabel").pack()
window.mainloop()
```

The "second style" block incorrectly affects the "first style" block despite being unrelated. If you comment out the second block, the font of the first block will change to the expected one. What's even more curious is that if you use a different python variable name in the second style (ie change `this_is_the_font_object` to `foo` in the second block only), the font won't be changed in the "first style". What's causing this? Is this a bug?

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this kind of weird stuff happens when the font object is destroyed. Basically the object gets destroyed despite tkinter having a reference to it. Can someone more knowledgeable please check this? tyvm

Comment: with `del this_is_the_font_object` I am getting the same issue, so I assume this is some sort of problem with python's garbage collection. the font must not be destroyed in python while tkinter's loop is active